# A view with six gallery widgets that are vertically stacked

Tags: android, gallery, scrollview

I want to create a screen with six image gallery widgets. the six different widgets will be vertically stacked/arranged. It should be possible to vertically scroll.

The implementation is like the one in current BBC android application in the market(https://market.android.com/details?id=bbc.mobile.news.uk)

I tried placing the six gallery widget in a Scroll View. But the vertical scroll is not smooth. I think my implementation is not correct. What should be the way I havve to proceed to create the BBC app UI?

```
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery1">
        </Gallery>
        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery2">
        </Gallery>
        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery3">
        </Gallery>
        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery4">
        </Gallery>
        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery5">
        </Gallery>

        <Gallery android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/gallery6">
        </Gallery>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post your current attempt? specifically the xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on Hardware acceleration helped to smmothen the scroll.